# How to Create Nested Data Frame

Tags: list, r, dataframe

I have a data that looks like this.

```
> file1="dat1.tab"
> file2="dat2.tab"
> dat1<-read.table(file1)
> print(dat1)
 V1 V2
1  1 43
2  1 43
3  1 43
>
> dat2<-read.table(file2)
> print(dat2)
 V1 V2
1  1 43
2  1 21
3  1 43
4  1 43
5  1 24
6  0 24
>
```

The column V1 refer to labels and V2 to prediction score.

How can I create a data structure called HIV, that looks like this:

```
> HIV
$hiv.dat1
$hiv.dat1$predictions
$hiv.dat1$predictions[[1]]
[1] 43 43 43
$hiv.dat$labels
$hiv.dat$labels[[1]]
[1] 1 1 1

$hiv.dat2
$hiv.dat2$predictions
$hiv.dat$predictions[[1]]
[1] 43 21 43 43 24 24
$hiv.dat2$labels
$hiv.dat2$labels[[1]]
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 0
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that?  It seems unlikely to produce a data structure that is easier to work with.

Answer (score 4):

"Nested data frame" has taken on a specific meaning since this question was asked.  In 2016, it would probably be interpreted as follows:

```r
dat1 <- data.frame(labels = rep(1, 3), predictions = rep(43, 3))
dat2 <- data.frame(labels = c(rep(1, 5), 0),
                   predictions = c(43, 21, 43, 43, 24, 24))
dat1
#>   labels predictions
#> 1      1          43
#> 2      1          43
#> 3      1          43
dat2
#>   labels predictions
#> 1      1          43
#> 2      1          21
#> 3      1          43
#> 4      1          43
#> 5      1          24
#> 6      0          24

dat <- list(HIV = 1:2, data = list(dat1, dat2))
attr(dat, "row.names") <- 1:2
class(dat) <- c("tbl_df", "data.frame")

dat # nested data frame, using the "tidyr" package definition of "nest"
#>   HIV                                     data
#> 1   1                      1, 1, 1, 43, 43, 43
#> 2   2 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 43, 21, 43, 43, 24, 24
str(dat)
#> Classes 'tbl_df' and 'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
#>  $ HIV : int  1 2
#>  $ data:List of 2
#>   ..$ :'data.frame': 3 obs. of  2 variables:
#>   .. ..$ labels     : num  1 1 1
#>   .. ..$ predictions: num  43 43 43
#>   ..$ :'data.frame': 6 obs. of  2 variables:
#>   .. ..$ labels     : num  1 1 1 1 1 0
#>   .. ..$ predictions: num  43 21 43 43 24 24

library(tidyr)
dat # nicer printing with the tidyr package
#> Source: local data frame [2 x 2]
#> 
#>     HIV               data
#>   (int)              (chr)
#> 1     1 <data.frame [3,2]>
#> 2     2 <data.frame [6,2]>
unnest(dat) # ordinary data frame representation
#> Source: local data frame [9 x 3]
#> 
#>     HIV labels predictions
#>   (int)  (dbl)       (dbl)
#> 1     1      1          43
#> 2     1      1          43
#> 3     1      1          43
#> 4     2      1          43
#> 5     2      1          21
#> 6     2      1          43
#> 7     2      1          43
#> 8     2      1          24
#> 9     2      0          24
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort out the details, but roughly:

```
dat1 <- data.frame(V1 = rep(1, 5), V2 = sample(c(40:45), 5)
dat2 <- data.frame(V1 = sample(c(0,1), 5, replace = TRUE),
 V2 = sample(c(40:45), 5, replace = TRUE))

> hiv <- list(hiv.dat1 = as.list(dat1), hiv.dat2 = as.list(dat2))
> hiv
$hiv.dat1
$hiv.dat1$V1
[1] 1 1 1 1 1

$hiv.dat1$V2
[1] 41 42 43 40 44


$hiv.dat2
$hiv.dat2$V1
[1] 0 1 1 0 0

$hiv.dat2$V2
[1] 42 43 40 44 43
```

Comment: @RL: Thanks. But it gives "$hiv.dat1$V1" instead of "$hiv.dat1$V1[[1]]". Is there a way to achieve that? Secondly how can one name V1 to "labels"?